# Google Apps shared contacts API get a contact for python

Tags: python, google-api

I'm having some issues trying to pull a shared contact using the gdata api for python that Google provides. Here is what I have to get the contacts.. but they are not all listed there

```
feed = gd_client.GetContactsFeed()
for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
    print entry.title
```

I can't figure out how to pull out a single contact so I can edit the contact information..

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google API lacks of features here.
You need to query all your contacts and then iter on them like this:

```
feedquery = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery()
feedquery.query.max_results = 1000
gmlf = gd_client.GetContactsFeed(feedquery.ToUri())
for index,gmc in enumerate(gmlf.entry):
        print str(index) +":"+ gmc .title.text
```

Remember to set `query.max_results` to your needs because by default is set to 25 contacts max;
this is probably the reason because they are not all listed after your query.
You can't retrieve one specific contact; you need to retrieve all and filter them using their email or title.

Comment: I am using the v3.0 protocol.GAE raise this:AttributeError: 'ContactsQuery' object has no attribute 'query'
the line should change to feedquery.max_results = 1000 according to http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/reference.html#Parameters